# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined for global variables

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I am trying to check if `bridgeObject.checkStatus` has been called already with the `isRunning` *global variable*.

If it hasn't then I call it and set `isRunning` to `true`. 
Then when it's dont change is running back to false.

```js
if (!this.isRunning){
  this.isRunning = true;
  bridgeObject.checkStatus().then(() => {
    this.isRunning = false;
  });
} else {
  console.log('Not allowed to checkstatus, Value isRunning= ' + this.isRunning); 
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined for global variables

I'm super new to programming so I haven't been able to figure out why I'm getting this error and what to do based on other answers here.

UPDATE:

Here is what checkStatus does

```
    checkStatus: function (mediaUrl) {
  console.log('bridge checkStatusOnDevice');
  if (typeof (Device) != 'undefined' && Device!= null) {
    Device.checkStatusOnDevice();
  }
  else
  {
    deviceStatusSuccess();
  }
},
```

Comment: How is function `checkStatus` defined, can you [edit] your question and post more code, please!

Comment: `checkStatus()` does not return anything, so its result is `undefined`. And `undefined` has no methods, including `then()`, which it does not have either. `then()` is not some magical entity, but an actual method of [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s.

Comment: `this.isRunning` is not a *global variable* for sure, it is a field of an object. You should describe what goal you are trying to achieve, so far it is hard to figure out from these pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checkStatus` function does not return anything - thus the result is `undefined`. You then try to call `then` on the result of your `checkStatus` function, which leads to your error message.

You need to make your `checkStatus` function return a promise if it is running asynchronously and you want to call `then` on the result.

This could look something like this:

```
checkStatus: function (mediaUrl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     console.log('bridge checkStatusOnDevice');

     if (typeof (Device) != 'undefined' && Device!= null) {
       // call resolve/reject when the following call succeeded/failed respectively
       Device.checkStatusOnDevice();

       // This COULD be something like this, if the API is callback based:
       // Device.checkStatusOnDevice(() => resolve(), () => reject())
     } else {
       // call resolve/reject when the following call succeeded/failed respectively
       deviceStatusSuccess();
     }
  });
},
```